# Screen capture window .NET control/library

Tags: .net, screenshot

I'm looking for a control or library to capture what an application is showing on screen in particular IE/Firefox.

My app will open an instance of IE to a web page.  User does what she needs to do on page then when he clicks button in my app to capture screen of IE/Firefox.  My app saves image to db.

I started to write it myself but with IE and tabs it's tricky to get process id.  So was wondering if anyone out there is using something.  Free or not does not matter.

Thanks,

Rick